# Downcasting base class instance to empty child interface

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, downcast

I was wondering about the validity of downcasting a base child to an empty interface child class. See example below. Basically I want to store data in a generic template free way (reading data from a file that can be any simple arithmetic type. `std::is_arthmetic<T>` should always be true in the following example).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

/**
 * Mother class holding data.
 */
class NonTypedData
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> data_;

    public:

    NonTypedData(std::size_t size) : data_(size) {}

    std::size_t size() const { return data_.size(); }

    const uint8_t* get() const { return data_.data(); }
          uint8_t* get()       { return data_.data(); }
};

/**
 * Empty child interface class that handles typed access
 */
template <typename T>
struct TypedData : public NonTypedData
{
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, "TypedData not supported for non arithmetic types.");

    const T* get() const { return reinterpret_cast<const T*>(this->NonTypedData::get()); }
          T* get()       { return reinterpret_cast<      T*>(this->NonTypedData::get()); }
    std::size_t size() const { return this->NonTypedData::size() / sizeof(T); }
};

template <typename T>
void fill(TypedData<T>& data)
{
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        data.get()[i] = i;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void print(const TypedData<T>& data)
{
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << ' ' << data.get()[i];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    NonTypedData data(10*sizeof(int));

    fill(static_cast<TypedData<int>&>(data));
    print(static_cast<const TypedData<int>&>(data));

    return 0;
}
```

I strongly feel that this is undefined-behavior but I am not sure about it. Is it?

In the other hand, I find this king of construct very useful and I feel there is probably a way to do something like this without being in UB-land. What do you think? A reference to `NonTypedData` instance in a `TypedData` instance maybe?

Comment: The cast leads indeed to UB, You might want placement new...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static_cast<const TypedData<int>&>(data)
```

You can't do that. You mustn't use a `static_cast` for a down-cast to a type unrelated to the actual type at the storage location of `data`. That part is already UB.

```
reinterpret_cast<const T*>(this->NonTypedData::get());
```

You can't do this either. You can only cast this back to `T` if the pointer has *originally* pointed to storage location of type `T`. You allocated storage explicitly for `uint8_t` which has weaker (weakest possible) requirements.

So in order to access it, you need to state (with `std::bit_cast`) that you are explicitly accessing storage of an incompatible type.

This makes a huge difference in the compiled code! The compiler may emit instructions with hard alignment constraints when accessing the storage location of the assumed type. A `std::bit_cast` or `memcpy` will not actually "copy" the data (with optimizations enabled), but it *will* force the compiler to be careful about *not* assuming alignment and alike.

---

It's both the same basic mistake: C++ will permit a lot of static / reinterpreting casts between pointers, but the result of the cast (except when casting up to pointers to byte/uint8_t, they are special) is only ever defined if the pointer was originally pointing at an object of the target type.

The cast itself is already UB. Accessing the memory by a pointer obtained via UB is twice so.

Comment: Okay I see. I should probably have used an example closer to my real case. I have to read a file with a data array made of samples that can be a type from a fixed set of arithmetic type (uint16_t, float...). I have all the metadata I need in the file to retrieve at runtime what type is the array in the file. If I understand well what you say, I have to read the file to an array that was allocated with the right type to begin with ? What if I allocated data with malloc instead ? From cppreference "that is suitably aligned for any scalar type"

Comment: Malloc works, "mostly" because it's required to give you storage conformant with the strongest possible alignment requirements for built-in types, yes. Just beware that this does not hold true for stuff like 128bit types and larger. It's only true for C standard types up to `long long`, `long double` or `void*`, whatever is largest! And there are certain benefits like cacheline- or page-alignment which make even 64 byte or 4k alignments a common thing for complex types.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<uint8_t> data_;
uint8_t* get()       { return data_.data(); }
T* get()       { return reinterpret_cast<      T*>(this->NonTypedData::get()); }
data.get()[i] = i;
```

`data.get()[..]` dereferences `uint8_t` data stored in vector using a pointer to `int`. That is undefined behavior - there is no `int` inside `uint8_t` array. There are `uint8_t` values, you can use pointers to `uint8_t` to dereference it, not any other type.

> What do you think ?

It's invalid.

If you want an `int` from `uint8_t` use bit shifts and mathematical operations. As a last resort, if you want to interpret bit patters stored in an `uint8_t` array as an `int`, use `memcpy` or `std::bit_cast` (which does `memcpy`).

> A reference to NonTypedData instance in a TypedData instance maybe?

No.

Comment: I assume you are referring to the strict aliasing rule ? Casting a char pointer is an exception to this rule (I should probably have used char instead of uint8_t). So as I understand it, the strict-aliasing rule allows cast form char* to any type and vise-versa as long as you can guaranty that the underlying data bytes indeed represents the type you cast to.

Comment: How can you check what the effective type of the data is? `std::vector<uint8_t>` has only `uint8_t`. I do not understand.

Comment: This is only an example of what I want to does. But actually my question is about the downcast from the NonTypedData instance to TypedData reference. Not about the cast from uint8_t* to T*. (And I did not represented in the example how I know the data storage effectively contains ints)